# Dismiss a component when switching the tab navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have an app with Bottom Tab Navigation. In one of those Tabs I have a Stack Navigation. I go to a second screen. When I change tabs using the bottom tab and return to the one I have the stack navigation, it is still on the second screen.

Is it possible that when you go away from that screen and then return, it goes back to the original "initialRouteName" screen.

Here is the code for my stack navigator.

```
export default class EScreen extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name="Home"
                        options={{
                            headerShown: false
                        }}
                        component={HomeScreen}
                    />
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name="Details"
                        component={DetailsScreen}
                        params={{data: []}}
                    />
                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: which react-navigation version are you using?

Comment: Your Information is not sufficient to get your point; please add your code in action.

Comment: "react-navigation": "^4.3.8",